# why the count value does not change after unnesting data in certain date range in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics

I want to count the number of event in certain web page location using BigQuery, I expect the results should be like this

| page_location | page_views | contact_support |
| --- | --- | --- |
| https://blueraycargo.id/ | 100 | 20 |
| https://blueraycargo.id/anotherPage1 | 50 | 8 |
| https://blueraycargo.id/anotherPage2 | 27 | 4 |

after exporting Google Analytics event to BigQuery, the data structure in BigQuery is like this

[image]

then I run this query in my BigQuery console

```
SELECT
page_location,
COUNT(IF(event_name = "page_view", event_name, NULL)) as page_view,
COUNT(IF(event_name = "contact_support", event_name, NULL)) as contact_support,
FROM (
  SELECT
    (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = "page_location") AS page_location,
    event_name,
  FROM
    `blueray-cargo.analytics_111111111111.events_*`
    WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20230423" AND "20230427"
    AND event_name = "page_view"
    OR event_name = "contact_support"
)
WHERE page_location = "https://blueraycargo.id/"
GROUP BY page_location
```

as you can see, I have `_TABLE_SUFFIX` so I can set the date range.

when I use `WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20230419" AND "20230427"` the result is

| page_location | page_views | contact_support |
| --- | --- | --- |
| https://blueraycargo.id/ | 300 | 27 |

and when I set the date range to be longer `WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20230411" AND "20230427"` the result is

| page_location | page_views | contact_support |
| --- | --- | --- |
| https://blueraycargo.id/ | 568 | 27 |

as you can see, after changing the date range, the number of `contact_support` event will still the same (27), I believe the total number of `contact_support` event should be different after prolong the date range. what went wrong in here?

Comment: First of all, you seem to need parenthesis at `WHERE` clause.   `WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20230423" AND "20230427"
    AND (event_name = "page_view" OR event_name = "contact_support")`  or `event_name IN ("page_view", "contact_support")`.

Comment: @Jaytiger yup thats the problem, thank you very much.  I have to use `event_name IN` instead of using `OR` . I will accept your answer if you post it below :)